# Avoid cmake to add the flags -search_paths_first and -headerpad_max_install_names in MacOS

Tags: macos, cmake, arm

I'm building an `*.elf` file for `ARM` within MacOS using `cmake`. `CMake` is adding the flags `-Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_name` automatically, which leads to produce an invalid `*.elf` file. I obtain the error `warning: cannot find entry symbol arch_paths_first; defaulting to 00000000080001e0`.

I have tried to execute the arm gcc command without that options and it works perfectly.

How can I stop `cmake` to add these flags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a way to do that.

It's necessary to add the following directive:

```
set(HAVE_FLAG_SEARCH_PATHS_FIRST 0)
```

I'm pretty sure that it must be added before the `project` directive.

For removing the flag `-headerpad_max_install_names`, I have written the following after the `project` directive:

```
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "")
```

I guess that if I were using `g++` I should needed to add

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "")
```

Comment: You are, sir, my hero.