# Setting Ninja values through CMake (cross compilation)

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cross-compiling, ninja

I am currently trying to cross compile a program I wrote on macOS to Linux, and I have had to make some changes to the `build.ninja` file to make that possible (specifically the linker commands/other places where libraries are linked). However, this gets wiped when I reconfigure CMake. Is there a way that I could use CMake to set the values in my Ninja file instead of wherever they are being set from? I am also using vcpkg for this project with GCC 10.2.0 for x86_64 Linux. The ninja files had to be trimmed to fit under the character limit, I can find a different way to put up the complete ones if needed. Here are my current CMakeLists, the first being my top level one and the second being the one that links everything:

```
Removed to make room for edits, working file can be found in edit 2
```

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for ImpromptuServer, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

add_subdirectory("database")
add_subdirectory("web")
add_subdirectory("api")
add_subdirectory("utils")

# Add source to this project's executable.
file(GLOB_RECURSE web ./web/*.cpp ./web/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE database ./database/*.cpp ./datbase/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE api ./api/*.cpp ./api/*.hpp)

add_library(libweb ${web})
add_library(libdata ${database})
add_library(libapi ${api})

add_executable(ImpromptuServer "ImpromptuServer.cpp" ${web} ${database} ${api})

set(ALL_LIBS Wt::Wt Wt::Dbo Wt::HTTP Wt::DboSqlite3 cryptopp-static json11 OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto cpr)

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
target_link_libraries(ImpromptuServer PRIVATE ${ALL_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(libweb PRIVATE Wt::Wt Wt::Dbo Wt::HTTP Wt::DboSqlite3)
target_link_libraries(libdata PRIVATE Wt::Wt Wt::Dbo Wt::HTTP Wt::DboSqlite3)
target_link_libraries(libapi PRIVATE ${ALL_LIBS})
```

I know `GLOB_RECURSE` is not best practice, but I don't want to change it unless it will fix my problem. Here is my original `build.ninja` file:

```
REMOVED due to irrelevancy to question.
```

Here is the one that I modified to get working:

```
REMOVED due to irrelevancy to question.
```

However, even when I compile successfully with the modified ninja file, I get this output message and the code fails to run on a Linux machine:

```
/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol arch_paths_first; defaulting to 0000000000414000
```

The code runs fine when compiling for macOS and using the original `build.ninja` file.

## Edit 1

After a lot of work, I have gotten CMake to use the toolchain file, but I still have a lingering problem where CMake can't find `Threads::Threads`. Here is my current `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
Working file can be found in edit 2
```

Here is the output message that I get:

```
[main] Configuring folder: ImpromptuServer 
[cmake] -- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib   
[cmake] -- Found ZLIB: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11") 
[cmake] -- Found CURL: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.tbd (found version "7.64.1")  
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:331 (_add_executable):
[cmake]   Target "ImpromptuServer" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target
[cmake]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[cmake]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:331 (_add_executable):
[cmake]   Target "ImpromptuServer" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target
[cmake]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[cmake]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:331 (_add_executable):
[cmake]   Target "ImpromptuServer" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target
[cmake]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[cmake]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:331 (_add_executable):
[cmake]   Target "ImpromptuServer" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target
[cmake]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[cmake]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libapi" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libapi" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libapi" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libapi" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libdata" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libdata" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libdata" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libdata" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libweb" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libweb" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libweb" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libweb" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
[main] Configuring folder: ImpromptuServer 
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True -Wno-dev -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/bin/x86_64-linux-gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/bin/x86_64-linux-g++ -H/Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/C++/ImpromptuServer -B/Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/C++/ImpromptuServer/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] INFO Using Linux protocols
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:331 (_add_executable):
[cmake]   Target "ImpromptuServer" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target
[cmake]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[cmake]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:331 (_add_executable):
[cmake]   Target "ImpromptuServer" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target
[cmake]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[cmake]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:331 (_add_executable):
[cmake]   Target "ImpromptuServer" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target
[cmake]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[cmake]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:331 (_add_executable):
[cmake]   Target "ImpromptuServer" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target
[cmake]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[cmake]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libapi" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libapi" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libapi" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libapi" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libdata" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libdata" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libdata" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libdata" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libweb" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libweb" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libweb" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:360 (_add_library):
[cmake]   Target "libweb" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   ImpromptuServer/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

## Edit 2

Everything now configures correctly with this CMake file:

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project (ImpromptuServer C CXX)

if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL AppleClang)
    #set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/Utilities/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
    set(LIB_DIR /Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/Utilities/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/debug/lib)
    add_compile_options(-std=c++17)
    find_package(threads REQUIRED)
else()
    message(INFO " Using Linux protocols")
    if(NOT ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} STREQUAL /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
        message(FATAL_ERROR " Incorrect toolchain file")
    endif()

    add_compile_options(-std=gnu++17)

    #set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
    set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING true)
    set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
    set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)
    set(LIB_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib)
    set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/)

    # Find libraries, may be changed later
    set(wt_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/share/wt/)
    set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/openssl)
    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/lib/)
    set(cryptopp_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/share/cryptopp/)
    set(cpr_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/share/cpr/)

    # Find pthread
    set(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/lib/libpthread.a)

    include_directories(/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/lib/)
    include_directories(/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/lib64/)
    include_directories(/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/)
    include_directories(/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/linux/)
    include_directories(/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/)
    #include_directories(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include)

    #set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS true)
    #set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/)
    #set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/)
    #add_link_options(-g -isysroot /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux)
    find_package(boost REQUIRED)
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
endif()

# Install packages
find_package(wt REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(cryptopp CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(cpr CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_library(json11 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(json11 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIB_DIR}/libjson11.a)

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("ImpromptuServer")
```

But I get a ton of errors like this:

```
[main] Building folder: ImpromptuServer 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/C++/ImpromptuServer/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 22
[build] [22/29   3% :: 0.087] Building CXX object ImpromptuServer/CMakeFiles/libapi.dir/api/internal/ios/AppStore.cpp.o
[build] [23/29   6% :: 0.091] Building CXX object ImpromptuServer/CMakeFiles/ImpromptuServer.dir/api/internal/ios/AppStore.cpp.o
[build] [24/29  10% :: 1.946] Building CXX object ImpromptuServer/CMakeFiles/ImpromptuServer.dir/web/pages/About.cpp.o
[build] FAILED: ImpromptuServer/CMakeFiles/ImpromptuServer.dir/web/pages/About.cpp.o 
[build] /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/bin/x86_64-linux-g++ --sysroot=/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/ -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK -I/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/lib -I/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/lib64 -isystem /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include -isystem /usr/local/include -isystem /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/openssl -isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -g -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT ImpromptuServer/CMakeFiles/ImpromptuServer.dir/web/pages/About.cpp.o -MF ImpromptuServer/CMakeFiles/ImpromptuServer.dir/web/pages/About.cpp.o.d -o ImpromptuServer/CMakeFiles/ImpromptuServer.dir/web/pages/About.cpp.o -c ../ImpromptuServer/web/pages/About.cpp
[build] In file included from /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/localefwd.h:40,
[build]                  from /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/string:43,
[build]                  from /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/bitset:47,
[build]                  from /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/Wt/WWebWidget.h:11,
[build]                  from /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/Wt/WInteractWidget.h:10,
[build]                  from /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/Wt/WContainerWidget.h:10,
[build]                  from ../ImpromptuServer/web/pages/About.hpp:3,
[build]                  from ../ImpromptuServer/web/pages/About.cpp:1:
[build] /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-linux/bits/c++locale.h:52:23: error: 'uselocale' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'setlocale'?
[build]    52 |   extern "C" __typeof(uselocale) __uselocale;
[build]       |                       ^~~~~~~~~
[build]       |                       setlocale
[build] /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-linux/bits/c++locale.h:62:11: error: '__locale_t' does not name a type
[build]    62 |   typedef __locale_t  __c_locale;
[build]       |           ^~~~~~~~~~
[build] /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-linux/bits/c++locale.h:69:26: error: '__c_locale' does not name a type
[build]    69 |   __convert_from_v(const __c_locale& __cloc __attribute__ ((__unused__)),
[build]       |                          ^~~~~~~~~~
[build] /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-linux/bits/c++locale.h: In function 'int std::__convert_from_v(const int&, char*, int, const char*, ...)':
[build] /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-linux/bits/c++locale.h:75:5: error: '__c_locale' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '__cloc'?
[build]    75 |     __c_locale __old = __gnu_cxx::__uselocale(__cloc);
[build]       |     ^~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |     __cloc
[build] /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-linux/bits/c++locale.h:100:28: error: '__old' was not declared in this scope
[build]   100 |     __gnu_cxx::__uselocale(__old);
[build]       |                            ^~~~~
[build] /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-linux/bits/c++locale.h:100:33: error: '__gnu_cxx::__uselocale' cannot be used as a function
[build]   100 |     __gnu_cxx::__uselocale(__old);
[build]       |                                 ^
```

## Edit 3

Here is my CMake output:

```
[main] Configuring folder: ImpromptuServer 
[driver] Removing /Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/C++/ImpromptuServer/build/CMakeCache.txt
[driver] Removing /Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/C++/ImpromptuServer/build/CMakeFiles
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True -Wno-dev -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/bin/x86_64-linux-gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/bin/x86_64-linux-g++ -H/Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/C++/ImpromptuServer -B/Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/C++/ImpromptuServer/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
[cmake] -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
[cmake] -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
[cmake] -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
[cmake] -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - no
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/bin/x86_64-linux-gcc - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
[cmake] -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
[cmake] -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
[cmake] -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - no
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/bin/x86_64-linux-g++ - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] INFO Using Linux protocols
[cmake] -- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.72.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.72.0")  
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread.h
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread.h - not found
[cmake] -- Found Threads: TRUE  
[cmake] -- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib   
[cmake] -- Found ZLIB: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11") 
[cmake] -- Found CURL: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.tbd (found version "7.64.1")  
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/C++/ImpromptuServer/build
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
```

Comment: What do you want to **achieve** by changing `build.ninja`? Is CMake picked wrong libraries by `find_package` and you want to pick other ones? Or does CMake use wrong compiler? By viewing just original and modified `build.ninja` it is difficult to understand what do you want to achieve and to suggest CMake approach to the problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev What I want to do is have the executable link to different libraries and have the macOS-specific linker flags that link against the system library (like `-framework`)  removed and instead have them link against some Linux kernel headers I have installed. CMake does use the correct compiler.

Comment: "I like this *square*, but I want it to be without *corners*". You seems want to **cross-compile**, which in CMake requires to use a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). Without a toolchain file CMake treats you project to be compiled natively. E.g. when you use `find_package`, it finds a package for the **host machine**, not for the target. You may even see that in `cmake` output. Specifying `-isysroot` in the `CMakeLists.txt` is almost always wrong: this setting is only for a toolchain file.

Comment: Funny you should mention that. I actually _do_ have a toolchain file. I have two in fact. One of which works but only has some of the Linux libraries I need, while the other has all of the libraries I need but it makes the CMake configure lock up and I end up needing to kill the process. This might be because I brought over the latter file from a Linux installation due to installation issues on macOS, but I'm hoping that's not the issue. However, I did not know that `-isysroot` was wrong, so I'll remove it.

Comment: I would prefer getting the other toolchain file working, but I want to at least remove the `FLAGS` section of the Ninja linking script as well as some of the `LINK_LIBRARIES` by using CMake.

Comment: E.g. `wt` library (`libwtd.a`,  `libwtdbod.a` files) is found by `find_package(wt REQUIRED)` call. You need to tell this call to use library installed for the **target** machine instead for the **host** one. With a toolchain file this is performed by setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` or `CMAKE_SYSROOT`. Without a toolchain file... it would be a bad game.

Comment: I have made some changes and I got the toolchain file working, but I can't figure out why CMake can't find this strange `Threads` package.

Comment: The code under `else` branch **after** the `project()` call is never a **toolchain**! Toolchain is a **separate file**, passed to CMake via `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` option. If you already use this option for `vcpkg`... well, I don't know what to do in that case. From my understanding, if you have `vcpkg` properly set for cross-compile purposes, then it should provide the whole toolchain for cross-compile.

Comment: I have a toolchain file specified in a different place because it wouldn't work correctly in the `CMakeLists.txt`. Everything now configures correctly but now I'm getting tons of build errors.

Comment: "Everything now configures correctly" - Are you sure in that? When `project()` is called, CMake checks the compiler and compiling environment, and stores results of these checks. So further changing of the compiler environment (like setting `CMAKE_SYSROOT`) only confuses CMake.

Comment: I'll edit the post with my config output. - Done

Comment: According to CMake output, you have 4 libraries - Boost, OpenSSL, ZLIB, CURL - found under `/usr` or `MacOSX10.15.sdk`. Do you name that as "configures correctly" when you are **cross-compiling** for Linux?

Comment: Well I've been trying to find variables that change those paths, but I don't know what they are. I was able to do it for the Threads library, so there might be variables for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of trying to get this to work, I finally have a solution. The solution came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54482519/avoid-cmake-to-add-the-flags-search-paths-first-and-headerpad-max-install-name) answer. Here is my final working CMake file that can compile for both MacOS and Linux:

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
# Target-specific stuff to be done before creating the project
if(${USE_LINUX})
    # Prevents linker from not finding program entry point
    set(HAVE_FLAG_SEARCH_PATHS_FIRST 0)
endif()
project (ImpromptuServer CXX)

if(NOT ${USE_LINUX})
    message(INFO " Using MacOS protocols")
    if(NOT ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} STREQUAL /Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/Utilities/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
        message(FATAL_ERROR " Incorrect toolchain file")
    endif()
    set(LIB_DIR /Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/Utilities/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/debug/lib)
    add_compile_options(-std=c++17)
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

else()
    message(INFO " Using Linux protocols")
    if(NOT ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} STREQUAL /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
        message(FATAL_ERROR " Incorrect toolchain file")
    endif()

    set(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "")
    add_compile_options(-std=gnu++17)
    add_link_options(-Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries)

    set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING true)
    # Get rid of OSX SDK to prevent incorrect linking
    set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "/Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/")

    set(LIB_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib)
    set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /)

    # Find libraries, may be changed later
    set(wt_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/share/wt/)
    set(cryptopp_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/share/cryptopp/)
    set(cpr_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/share/cpr/)

    set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/openssl)
    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/lib/)
    # Cheat a little bit by linking a dynamic library
    set(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/lib/libcrypto.a)
    set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS true)

    # Special system library include directories
    set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/)
    set(ZLIB_ROOT /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/lib/)
    set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/curl/)

    # Find pthread and link to non-apple
    set(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/lib/libpthread.a)

    # GCC includes
    include_directories(SYSTEM /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux/10.2.0/include/)
    # System includes
    include_directories(SYSTEM /Volumes/CaseSensitive/cross/x86_64-linux/include/c++/10.2.0/)

    #set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/)
    set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE on)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS true)
    set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/installed/x64-linux/lib/)
    find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options filesystem thread chrono date_time REQUIRED)
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
endif()

# Install packages
find_package(wt REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(cryptopp CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(cpr CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_library(json11 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(json11 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIB_DIR}/libjson11.a)

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("ImpromptuServer")
```

While all of the paths are system-specific, this could be improved later with some more advanced scripting. Here are the arguments I pass in on MacOS and Linux respectively:

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/jackhogan/Desktop/Code/Utilities/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DUSE_LINUX=false
```

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Volumes/CaseSensitive/vcpkgLinux/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DUSE_LINUX=true
```