# Cross-compile for Windows from macOS? - i686-w64-mingw32-ld: Error: unable to disambiguate: -search_paths_first (did you mean --search_paths_first ?)

Tags: xcode, cmake, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

Trying to cross compile, here is the minimal example `CMakeLists.txt`

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(hello VERSION 0.0.0 LANGUAGES C)
set(src "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src/main.c")
file(WRITE "${src}" "int main(){}")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "${src}")
```

```sh
$ brew install mingw-w64
$ mkdir 'cmake-build-win64-debug' && cd "$_"
$ cmake .. \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='Debug' \
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER='i686-w64-mingw32-gcc' \
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER='i686-w64-mingw32-g++'

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.3.0
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - no
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc - broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/local/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: cmake-build-win64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_f30ca/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f30ca.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f30ca.dir/build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f30ca.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/local/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f30ca.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c cmake-build-win64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_f30ca
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_f30ca.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/local/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/cmTC_f30ca.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_f30ca 
    /usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/8.0.0_4/toolchain-i686/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: Error: unable to disambiguate: -search_paths_first (did you mean --search_paths_first ?)
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_f30ca] Error 1
    make: *** [cmTC_f30ca/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "cmake-build-win64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "cmake-build-win64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

So I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482619, specifically with

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS='' \
-DHAVE_FLAG_SEARCH_PATHS_FIRST=0
```

But that didn't fix it. How do I build for Windows from macOS?

Comment: try with an updated and supported version of cmake, you are on v3 and check the syntax

Comment: @EgonStetmann I am on version 3.20 of CMake, with 3.0 being the minimum supported by my configuration.

Comment: When **cross-compile** you should use a [toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). Otherwise CMake thinks you are compiling for the host platform. E.g. it passes `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk` as a *sysroot*.